# Firebase Auth Emulator - Golang: Project not found

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

Recently I started testing my go server, which uses firebase admin sdk, with firebase local emulator suite. It works perfectly with firestore, but with the authentication not so much.

I tried many different approaches, including firebase demo project, my own demo project, and a simple test project. Nothing of those did the job; I kept receive the same error message, project not found.

## Firebase Emulator

I use the firebase admin SDK, and I followed the insructions in the
[official firebase article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#admin_sdks).

To configure the emulator, I ran `firebase init` and `firebase init emulators` in terminal. Those resulted in the files in the next section. Then the emulator starts with the command `firebase emulators:start`, and I added `--project test` to set the project ID.

## Simplified Code

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    }
  }
}
```

Simple JSON which describes the port for auth service.

**.firebaserc**

```
{}
```

This is empty because it doesn't have any project set, but I also tried adding projects here. Anyway, the project ID is set to "test" in both terminals, the one that runs the emulator, and the one that runs the golang app.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    firebase "firebase.google.com/go"
    "firebase.google.com/go/auth"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    config := &firebase.Config{ProjectID: "test"}
    app, _ := firebase.NewApp(ctx, config)
    Auth, _ := app.Auth(ctx)

    params := (&auth.UserToCreate{}).
        DisplayName("Some Name").
        Email("example@gmail.com").
        Password("password")

    _, err := Auth.CreateUser(ctx, params)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

On the final line it panics with error status 400 Bad Request, and message PROJECT_NOT_FOUND. It looks like the admin SDK is looking at a public project with project ID "test", and I'm trying to emulate a local project.

Firestore emulator works, Auth does not.
I haven't found a single solution for this in golang. In node.js admin SDK the local auth emulator works, but I need the golang admin SDK.

How can I tell the go admin SDK for firebase auth emulator to look for a local project?

Comment: Are you using v4? https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-go-v4

Comment: Thanks! I used v3.13.0, and firebase starts supporting auth emulator at v4.2.0